# How to get on behalf of SharePoint access in Teams app

Tags: azure, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-tabs-sso-sample-nodejs

I'm trying to change the final request of this sample to access the SharePoint REST API
I've added delegate permission in AzureAD and added the scope "https://microsoft.sharepoint-df.com/AllSites.FullControl" to the token request, but still getting 401

Comment: I'm not 100% sure offhand, but I think this example, based on the name, is request Graph SSO permissions, in particular OBO permissions. I don't think you can use SSO in this way for Teams - you'll need to explicitly use MSAL and request the permissions for your app. Depending on what you're trying to do though with SharePoint, the Graph Toolkit could also be useful as an alternate (it wraps some things up nicely).

Comment: Hi @591282, are you still facing the issue, could you please brief the scenario to mitigate the issue.

Comment: Hi @591282, are you still facing the issue ?

Comment: I've resolved the issue, similar to how Hilton Giesenow suggested, I had to modify the consent popup with the correct sharepoint scope request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Copping the answer from @Hilton's comments for better visibility**

Modify the consent popup with the correct sharepoint scope request. Based on the name, is request Graph SSO permissions, in particular OBO permissions. I don't think you can use SSO in this way for Teams - you'll need to explicitly use MSAL and request the permissions for your app. Depending on what you're trying to do though with SharePoint.